# issue with maven repository

Tags: java, maven

I just want to know if maven triggers automatically as soon as we add the dependency to pom.xml and save it?

because i just added one new dependency to my existing pom.xml, It gave me the below error

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-oxm:pom:3.0.5.RELEASE from/to nexus (http://vdidev-v1102-p:8081/nexus/content/groups/GroupMoodysFlexApps/): connection timed out to http://vdidev-v1102-p:8081/nexus/content/groups/GroupMoodysFlexApps/org/springframework/spring-oxm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.pom
```

Comment: Depends on your IDE.  Command line maven only runs when asked to.

Answer (score 0):

yes when you add dependency and invoke maven compile phase it has to download all dependency if it doesn't find it in local cache, if you are using some IDE (eclipse or something) they generally trigger compile when you save `pom.xml`

problem here is, it is not able to reach to this url

```
connection timed out to http://vdidev-v1102-p:8081/nexus/content/groups/GroupMoodysFlexApps/org/springframework/spring-oxm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-oxm-3.0.5.RELEASE.pom
```